# MySQL Select SUM of results ignoring LIMIT

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have a table full of 100 items and sales value for said items. In theory, I would like to be able to get the top 15 most selling items with a bottom row for their total sales (total of just the top 15), and have another column with the % Share of Sales of each item relative to  Total Sales (total of all items in the table).

I thought that maybe using rank, limit 15, and GROUP BY rank WITH ROLLUP would solve the first half of my problem, but I can't wrap my head around how after that I could reference the total sales of all 100 items to get the % share column.

Is this possible? Thanks a lot

Comment: Sample data and desired results.

Comment: What something else do you want except code below? I think it works right.

Comment: Generally, issues of data display are best resolved in application code

Answer (score 0):

It might be simplest to just do the calculation twice:

```
with i15 as (
      select t.item, sum(sales) as sales,
             sum(sales) / sum(sum(sales)) over () as sales_ratio
      from t
      group by t.item
      order by sum(sales) desc
      limit 15
     )
select item, sales, sales_ratio
from i15
union all
select 'total', sum(sales), sum(sales_ratio)
from i15;
```